# FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/

Tags: android

I try to get the path from the URI using this method :

```
 public  String getPath(Uri uri) {

    String result;
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
        result = uri.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        result = cursor.getString(idx);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;

}
```

When I try to compress the bitmap :

```
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
```

I get this error:

```
05-18 16:58:56.346 19080-19080 E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG_20160518_165856.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

05-18 16:58:56.346 19080-19080/E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG_20160518_165856.jpg: open failed : ENOENT (No such file or directory)

05-18 16:58:56.356 19080-19080/E/JHEAD: can't open '/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG_20160518_165856.jpg'
```

Comment: Does this file exists => `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG_20160518_165856.jpg` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Change this

public  String getPath(Uri uri) {

String result;
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
    result = uri.getPath();
} else {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
    result = cursor.getString(idx);
    cursor.close();
}
return result;

}

//To this and try

public  String getPath(Uri uri) {

String result;
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
    result = uri.getPath();
} else {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
Log.e("Tag", "idx " + idx);
    result = cursor.getString(idx);
    cursor.close();
}
return result;

}
```